# "Drop-down" selected value not updated in HTML

Tags: javascript, html-select, forms

When I select a new value (3) in a drop down menu, I see that HTML still has the old value (10) as "selected".

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
```

EDIT 1: the problem manifests itself when I clone the form. The cloned copy has its selected option reset. Is there a way to clone the selected value too?

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle?

Comment: The property is updated, so this is not an issue, what you're seeing is the attribute in the HTML

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not being able to see property changes when viewing the HTML.

Comment: The selected *attribute* sets the default selected option, it does not necessarily indicate the currently selected option. The selected *property* always indicates whether an option is currently selected or not.

Comment: How are you "detaching" the form? Likey you need to read the current values before detaching, then reassign them afterward. Same again when you reattach the form. Or change how the form is detached/reattached so the values aren't changed.

Comment: As I have stated in "EDIT 1" above, the problem manifests itself when I clone the form. The cloned copy has its selected option reset. Is there a way to clone the selected value too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this is that changing the selected index will not alter the attribute on the html element itself. However, the value actually is changed.

See [`this demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/CcP5L/) for an example of what the selected index shows when changed

Comment: why in this demo , the value is -1?,